# NSOutlineView as Source list with core data

Tags: cocoa, nsoutlineview

Im working on an app that needs a source list like the the ones found in Finder. So far I've gotten Core Data working with an `NSOutlineView` but the group headings don't look very source list like. A real source list group heading looks like [image] and the standered on in an `NSOutlineView` looks like [image]. It appears that the only major differences are text color and capital letters. Is it possible to change the color of only the group headings or is there a source list heading "theme" I can use?

Answer (score 2):

In Interface Builder make sure to set the TableView's Highlight value to [Source List](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000118-SW7) (the default is regular). Then make sure you implement the [`-outlineView:isGroupItem:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOutlineViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSOutlineViewDelegate/outlineView%3aisGroupItem%3a) delegate method and return YES for any group item.

Comment: I tried this earlier but im not sure I did it correctly. Could you give an example of how to do this?

Comment: In the -outlineView:isGroupItem: method check whether the item that is sent in should be a group item or not. This is based on your data, so you need to figure out how to determine that. Make sure that the controller that implements this method is set as the delegate of the outline view.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [SourceView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SourceView/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code in Apple's developer documentation. They provide a really good example of how to do this. It requires a bit of code in the NSOutlineView delegate, and there is no default "theme" or anything, but this should put you on the right track.

Comment: I did look at the code but its pretty far beyond me... Could you tell me what file sets the style of the groups?